# Check if Prototype is loaded

Tags: javascript, prototype

How can I check if Prototype is loaded/included in the page?
If I check the "Prototype" object and prototype isn't loaded I get "Prototype is not defined" error in firebug.

http://jsfiddle.net/pampurio97/evRTx/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `typeof` will pass with an undeclared/undefined object.

```
if ( typeof Prototype !== "undefined" ) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is slightly cleaner:

```
var Prototype = window.Prototype;
if(Prototype) { //Prototype is loaded }
```

Comment: Checking truthy vs checking undefined is different

Comment: Is there a link that explains that difference? I think that at least in this case the solutions are identical.